# Android switch color change

Tags: android, colors, switch-statement, controls

I need to change the default colors of the Switch control in Android (I'm using Xamarin, but it shouldn't be so different from native).

**Expected final template result:** https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch

This is the default switch control in Android 5.0, but I would like to change the color from green to another color in both track and thumb.

**What I'm doing**
I've found a method that is nearly working, but the result is not what I want. The method is:

```
var color = Color.Rgb(101, 127, 135);
NearSwitch.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
```

**Problem:** I cannot set the exact color in the track.
The color I'm setting is #657f87 or 101, 127, 135 in RGB, but, probably due to the PorterDuff mode and track template/transparency, the final color is not the one I've set.

If I try to change the PorterDuff mode to SRC or some other, I can see the track is a rectangle with two different colors instead of a single one with borders (as the default from Android).

I don't want to rewrite the entire template if possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your PorterDuff ist set to "Multiply". Therefore, your new Color will get mixed with the basic color of the switch.

Ty using:

```
NearSwitch.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: This generates another color (#bac5c9 or 186, 197, 201 in RGB) that is still not correct.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm into this issue too

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, I didn't (since it was working for me). Unfortunately, I'm not into this topic anymore and, hence, cannot give any further help.